# MS SQL Query returns 1

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

I have a mssql query which is working on SQL Server but when i embed it into PHP code it return nothing. i have worked alot in query and got some success but still an error. can anybody help me out of this please. I think the rvdbo.lookup table is not fetching result.
Server information
PHP Version 5.6.30
MSSQL enable

Error: Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
The data types varchar and text are incompatible in the add operator

```
    <?php 
    echo $details = "SELECT *
  FROM(
       SELECT ct.transactionTime,
              st.TrackingStatus AS EVENT,
              ct.consignmentNumber,
              ct.currentLocation AS LOCATION,
              CONVERT(nvarchar,c.bookingDate,105)AS BookingDate,
              CASE
              WHEN ct.stateID = '18' THEN 'Consignment Arrived At ' + ct.currentLocation + ' Main Office' + ' on ' + CONVERT(nvarchar,transactionTime,105)
              WHEN ct.stateID = '1' THEN ' Consignment Booked'
              WHEN ct.stateID = '2'
                OR ct.stateID = '3'
                OR ct.stateID = '4' THEN 'Processing at Origin HUB'
              WHEN ct.stateID = '5'
                OR ct.stateID = '6'
                OR ct.stateID = '7' THEN 'Reached at Destination HUB'
              WHEN ct.stateID = '8' THEN 'Shipment on route '
              WHEN ct.stateID = '10' THEN('Consignment is ' + (
                  SELECT CAST(CAST([AttributeValue] AS VARCHAR(100)) AS TEXT) AS field from rvdbo.lookup
                    WHERE Id = (
                          SELECT reason
                            FROM RunsheetConsignment
                            WHERE consignmentNumber = '591091000000051')))
              WHEN ct.stateID = '15' THEN 'Consignment has been ' + ct.reason + ' ' + CONVERT(nvarchar,transactionTime,105) + ' in ' + ct.currentLocation
              END AS Detail
         FROM Consignment_Tracking_View AS ct
              INNER JOIN Consignment AS c ON ct.consignmentNumber = c.consignmentNumber
              INNER JOIN MNP_ConsginmentTrackingStatus AS st ON ct.stateID = st.StatusID
         WHERE c.consignmentNumber = '591091000000051' AND c.consignerAccountNo NOT IN('4B45','7240','4H86','4H87','4H88','4B87','7240','4B45','4H91','4H89','4H90','4F47'))AS A
  WHERE A.[EVENT] = 'NEW'
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT transactionTime,
                '' AS EVENT,
                consignmentNumber,
                LOCATION,
                BookingDate,
                detail
  FROM(
       SELECT CAST(ct.transactionTime AS date)AS transactionTime,
              st.TrackingStatus AS EVENT,
              ct.consignmentNumber,
              ct.currentLocation AS LOCATION,
              CONVERT(nvarchar,c.bookingDate,105)AS BookingDate,
              CASE
              WHEN ct.stateID = '18' THEN 'Consignment Arrived At ' + ct.currentLocation + ' Main Office' + ' on ' + CONVERT(nvarchar,transactionTime,105)
              WHEN ct.stateID = '1' THEN ' Consignment Booked'
              WHEN ct.stateID = '2'
                OR ct.stateID = '3'
                OR ct.stateID = '4' THEN 'Processing at Origin HUB'
              WHEN ct.stateID = '5'
                OR ct.stateID = '6'
                OR ct.stateID = '7' THEN 'Reached at Destination HUB'
              WHEN ct.stateID = '8' THEN 'Shipment on route '
              WHEN ct.stateID = '10' THEN('Consignment is ' + (
                  SELECT CAST(CAST([AttributeValue] AS VARCHAR(100)) AS TEXT) AS field from rvdbo.lookup
                    WHERE Id = (
                          SELECT reason
                            FROM RunsheetConsignment
                            WHERE consignmentNumber = '591091000000051')))
              WHEN ct.stateID = '15' THEN 'Consignment has been ' + ct.reason + ' ' + CONVERT(nvarchar,transactionTime,105) + ' in ' + ct.currentLocation
              END AS Detail
         FROM Consignment_Tracking_View AS ct
              INNER JOIN Consignment AS c ON ct.consignmentNumber = c.consignmentNumber
              INNER JOIN MNP_ConsginmentTrackingStatus AS st ON ct.stateID = st.StatusID
         WHERE c.consignmentNumber = '591091000000051' AND c.consignerAccountNo NOT IN('4B45','7240','4H86','4H87','4H88','4B87','7240','4B45','4H91','4H89','4H90','4F47'))AS A
  WHERE A.[EVENT] IN('MANIFESTED','BAGGED','LOADED')
UNION ALL
SELECT *
  FROM(
       SELECT ct.transactionTime,
              st.TrackingStatus AS EVENT,
              ct.consignmentNumber,
              ct.currentLocation AS LOCATION,
              CONVERT(nvarchar,c.bookingDate,105) AS BookingDate,
              CASE
              WHEN ct.stateID = '18' THEN 'Consignment Arrived At ' + ct.currentLocation + ' Main Office' + ' on ' + CONVERT(nvarchar,transactionTime,105)
              WHEN ct.stateID = '1' THEN ' Consignment Booked '
              WHEN ct.stateID = '2'
                OR ct.stateID = '3'
                OR ct.stateID = '4' THEN 'Processing at Origin HUB'
              WHEN ct.stateID = '5'
                OR ct.stateID = '6'
                OR ct.stateID = '7' THEN 'Reached at Destination HUB'
              WHEN ct.stateID = '8' THEN 'Shipment on route '
              WHEN ct.stateID = '10' THEN('Consignment is ' + (
                  SELECT CAST(CAST([AttributeValue] AS VARCHAR(100)) AS TEXT) AS field from rvdbo.lookup
                    WHERE Id = (
                          SELECT reason
                            FROM RunsheetConsignment
                            WHERE consignmentNumber = '591091000000051')))
              WHEN ct.stateID = '15' THEN 'Consignment has been ' + ct.reason + ' ' + CONVERT(nvarchar,transactionTime,105) + ' in ' + ct.currentLocation
              END AS Detail
         FROM Consignment_Tracking_View AS ct
              INNER JOIN Consignment AS c ON ct.consignmentNumber = c.consignmentNumber
              INNER JOIN MNP_ConsginmentTrackingStatus AS st ON ct.stateID = st.StatusID
         WHERE c.consignmentNumber = '591091000000051'
           AND c.consignerAccountNo NOT IN('4B45','7240','4H86','4H87','4H88','4B87','7240','4B45','4H91','4H89','4H90','4F47')) AS A
  WHERE A.[EVENT] IN('RUnsheet','POD')
  ORDER BY transactionTime DESC";

        //  $sql = trim(ob_get_clean());
            $rs1 = mssql_query($details);
            $num_rows_one = mssql_num_rows($rs1);
            //echo ($num_rows_one);
            if ($num_rows_one > 0){
                ?>
                <section class="Tracking-history">
                    <h4>Tracking History:</h4>
                    <table class="col-md-12 table-bordered table-striped table-condensed cf track-history">
                        <thead class="cf">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="background: #f26522;color: #FFF;">DateTime </td>
                                <td style="background: #f26522;color: #FFF;">Status</td>
                                <td style="background: #f26522;color: #FFF;">Location </td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>
                        <?php while($row1 = mssql_fetch_array($rs1)){ ?>
                            <tr> 
                                <td> <?php echo $row1["transactionTime"]; ?></td>
                                <td> <?php echo $row1["Detail"]; ?></td>
                                <td> <?php echo $row1["LOCATION"];?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php } ?>
```

Comment: where is your php code?

Comment: $rs1 = mssql_query($details);
   $num_rows_one = mssql_num_rows($rs1);
if ($num_rows_one > 0){
    ?>
    
      <?php while($row1 = mssql_fetch_array($rs1)){ ?>
       <tr> 
        <td> <?php echo $row1["transactionTime"]; ?></td>
        <td> <?php echo $row1["Detail"]; ?></td>
        <td> <?php echo $row1["LOCATION"];?></td>
       </tr>
       <?php } ?>

Comment: above my php code

Comment: try printing `$details` first and compare with your original query

Comment: i have echo $details, copy query from web page and paste it in sqlserver management it is working on it

Comment: `mssql_query` will be deprecated soon, have a look here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-query.php
Try `sqlsrv_query` instead.

Comment: Have a look at "page source" in your browser; it looks like your HTML tags are not properly closed; so it may not show up in normal view; or maybe the rest of the HTML code was omitted above.

Comment: ok but all the other querys' are working fine with mssql_query.

Comment: I have updated query and now give an error please look into this. thanks in advance
Error: Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
The data types varchar and text are incompatible in the add operator

Comment: actually the table has nvarchar datatype and values are not fetch. i have changes this to varchar